# Why can Newtonian gravity provide the correct value of the Schwarzschild radius?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, newtonian-gravity, dimensional-analysis, event-horizon

By using Newtonian gravity, we can equate the kinetic and potential energy of a test mass in order to obtain the escape velocity of an object from a large mass $M$:

$$\frac{1}{2} m v^2 = \frac{GMm}{r}$$

therefore:

$$v_{esc}^2 = \frac{2GM}{r}$$

We can then obtain the Schwarzschild radius $r_s$ by setting $v_{esc}$ to the speed of light $c$:

$$r_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$$

Is there a reason why Newtonian gravity gives the correct value of $r_s$? Some people seem to say it is just coincidence, others that the $\frac{G}{c^2}$ needs to be there to make the dimensionality correct, but the correct factor of 2 is just a coincidence. I have read [this short paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10701-009-9315-8) which seems to conclude that there is a reason this prediction is correct, although I admit my knowledge of General relativity is quite basic and I have a hard time following the argument.

Comment: correction: "I have read this short paper that is you can't read because it's behind a paywall", makes the question unanswerable...and when I had institutional access, it's pretty much unacceptable to be screwing around on PSE using  [the institutions] capital equipment.

Comment: $29.95  a pop, what a bargain!

Comment: @JEB - Welcome to the internet, there's a famous website that unlocks all the paywalls for free. Unfortunately it's against the forum rules to post the unlocked link, but since everybody already knows how to unlock it it's ok to post the official link, just copy the url and paste it into the unlocker. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub

Comment: @Yukterez blocked by my ISP.  I attempted to "find my way" around that but ended up in a nasty probably malware-infested mess of links then gave up.  I would not recommend it.

Comment: @m4r35n357 - in that case I wouldn't recommend your ISP, but the workaround is the same as with any other blocked website, most browsers like Brave or Opera have a built in free VPN or TOR  anyway.

Comment: @Yukterez I _don't_ recommend my ISP, but it is most likely a national requirement for all ISPs in my country.  Anyway I don't trust VPN "providers" - and I don't have brave or opera.